# Photoshop Freezes and Crashes on Startup

Tags: 14.04, wine, adobe, tools, photoshop

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Wine 1.7.51. I installed Adobe Photoshop CS and whenever I try to run Photoshop it gets to "initializing tools" and then freezes and I have to do the xkill command to close. Frustrated, I tried installing Adobe Photoshop CS2 and the exact same issue came up: I launch the program, it gets to "initializing tools" and then freezes and crashes.

I tried following [these instructions](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/photoshop-cs2-available-for-free-works-fine-in-wine) and they don't work. So I uninstalled and tried [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJSHfWcEDrM) and it didn't work either.

The only thing I can think of is that Photoshop simply doesn't work with Wine 1.7.51, but I don't know. It's really frustrating following these instructions to the letter and watching it work for everyone except me.

If no one can solve this issue I think I'm going to install Windows 7 and Photoshop on an external HD, but before I do I thought I'd take one last crack at this. I must have wasted over 12 hours in the past few weeks trying to get photoshop to run on ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried using playonlinux

Answer (score 1):

Please feel free to ignore this answer because it is not what you want to hear- but it is worth having a go with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) or Gimpshop.

I used to use Photoshop but I now find Gimp equally good and it will work without wine.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree to give Gimp a shot. The hard part is not learning Gimp it is un-learning PS (because Gimp doesn't try to be a PS clone). Gimpshop has been hijacked and is now a malware distribution medium. Besides Gimp, there are also plenty of other FOSS software for imaging, see [here](https://pixls.us/) for some information & discussion.